# Working with vectors in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have 2 vectors:

1) `xvn = [-6.2 -5.2 -4.2 -3.2 -2.2 -1.2 -0.2 0.8 1.8 2.8 3.8 4.8 5.8]`

2) `xg = [-2.0 -1.0 -0.0 1.0 2.0]`

I am trying to get a new vector which looks like this.

```
xv = [-6.2 -5.2 -4.2 -3.2 -2.2 -2.0 -1.0 -0.0 1.0 2.0 2.8 3.8 4.8 5.8]
```

Essentially `xg` has values say between -2.0 to 2.0 and `xvn` has values between -6.2 to 5.8. The new vector `xv` contains values of `xvn` up to -2.0, then all values of `xg` and values of `xvn` higher than 2.0.

All vectors are in increasing order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they're monotonically increasing, something like this:

```
xv = [xvn(xvn<xg(1)) xg xvn(xvn>xg(end))]
```

If they are column vectors instead of rows, as you've shown, then vertically concatenate (`;` or `vertcat`).

Comment: @ltxEnthu To accept the question, click on the tick mark in the upper left corner of the answer